# Getting started with cross platform augmented reality in 2016

Tags: android, ios, augmented-reality

I have to get started with augmented reality for a client. We're all web developers in my company. What would you suggest a small web developer team to build an app for iOS AND Android. Do we have to go native or is it possible and a good way to use for example Wikitude?

The app should recognise a stone in a city and play media.

What is the best approach for this app?

I appreciate any help!

Comment: If web developers are the only team who will build this app, then Wikitude is the good option, and you should opt for it. I have used its Phonegap plugin, is easy to use and fast to implement.